# How to play HTTP Live Streaming(HLS) in all PC browsers?

Tags: html, audio, browser, rtsp, http-live-streaming

We have stored audio sources in `WOWZA` server.We are searching a audio player to play audio in Web Browser over `RTMP` or `HTTP(HLS)`.
We have tested `HTML5` `audio tag`, but it does not support RTMP and HLS streaming.

**Tried :**

```
<audio controls autoplay>
<source src="http://host-name/path/playlist.m3u8" type="audio/mpegurl">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

**Questions :**

WHat about `Jplayer`,`JWplayer` and `flowplayer`?
Please let me know `appropriate audio player` for this or there is any solution in `HTML5` ?

Answer (score 1):

Only Safari 6.0+ has native HLS support.

JWplayer has HLS audio-only support:

[JWPlayer - Audio Demo](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430255-audio-only-streaming)

The open-source [mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) also supports HLS to a degree.

Comment: Thanks..!!..Can u please tell me what is the best alternative way to run hls on all mobile and desktop browsers..?

Comment: HLS is supported on newer versions of Android, although 4.4.3 and 4.4.3 still have some issues especially with live streams. I think the best way is to have a different stream for each device type. In Wowza you can activate a second RTSP output for older mobile devices but you'll need to make the decision regarding what stream to send to each client based on the detected capabilities of the connected device (generally by checking the User-Agent).

Comment: Thanks for your support..!!..`"different stream for each device type"` means we have to use physical streaming files instead of hls ?

Comment: Wowza supports live-streaming using different protocols, you just need to configure the "Playback types" on your live application. See [Understanding streaming protocols and output file formats](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?621-Understanding-streaming-protocols-and-output-file-formats#rtspstreaming) and [How to set up live streaming using an RTSP/RTP-based encoder](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?354-How-to-set-up-live-streaming-using-an-RTSP-RTP-based-encoder)

Comment: I totally agree with you..but my question is how can we run `rtsp` or `hls` on `html5 audio player` ?..we already run `rtsp` in low handset phones that is played on the native player of phone. How can we stream audio in html5 player ?

Answer (score 1):

There is one more option - Flowplayer Version 6.0: Cross-browser HLS.
But the catch is, it's only free if you use the GitHub hosted version (which displays the Flowplayer logo and branding). Otherwise you'll need to pay for it:

https://flowplayer.org/pricing/player.html#compare

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing (March 2018) options include Clappr (https://github.com/clappr/clappr, see [supported formats](https://github.com/clappr/clappr/blob/master/doc/SUPPORTED_FORMATS.md)) and MediaElement.js (https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement) -- both have cross-browser HLS support built-in care of the `hls.js` project and both players are free and open source.

For alternative players that may or may not require plugins to play HLS, see https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js#player-integration.